# Copying cell from one sheet to another without formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

probably a simple one to your geniuses however I need a fresh pair of eyes as I've been on this a while and can't see my error. I'm merely wanting to copy the contents of a cell from one cell to another cell on another sheet, but I don't want all the formatting to go with it, only the value.

My code is below

```
  Range("H" & Target.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Accepted Template").Range("P4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Any idea what I have done wrong here.  VBA keeps throwing out an unexpected end error.

Comment: You must always specify the worksheet when you use `Range`. I tell about *Range("H" & Target.Row).Copy*

Comment: If you obtain the error and cannot understand where is the point of it in a complex operator, divide this operator to a pack of simple operators (using a lot of proper temporary variables).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but if I take off the .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues the command actually works, all I am looking for is to have the content pasted without formatting.

Comment: Range.Copy have the only 'Destination' optional parameter. If it presents, its type is to be a Range. You want to use Range.PasteSpecial for this parameter - but Range.PasteSpecial is a method, not a property of Range type. Of course, Excel go mad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can try this Code will Copy Formatted cell value from Sheet 1 & Paste in Sheet 2 at destination cell/cells without Formatting (Only Value).*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3, A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- If you want to copy Formatted range then replace line `2` in the code
  with this, `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A10").Copy`

[image]

**Note,**

- This code can be used as Standard Module also.
- Just to test the code purposely I've used  2 destination cells, you
  may use one or even many.
- This can be done even by use of  **Paste Special** and **Value** option also.

Comment: Thanks so much, I wouldn't have took that approach, hence why I struggled, but that worked a treat thanks again, as I am aware you have helped me several times.

Comment: @Nokturnyl, extremely happy to help you, Plz keep asking, have nice time :-)